# Listen the button click of BLE device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.4-kitkat, android-bluetooth

I have one BLE device which has one physical button on it ,I want to perform some action in android device  whenever I click the BLE device button.
Can any body help me by pointing which method is going to call when the BLE device button is pressed 
I have setup a breakpoint in the BluetoothLeService.java from the android sample project but no luck so far.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.This is new thing for me sorry in advance

Thanks

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#notification

Comment: Thanks now able to get the characteristic and able to track the button event :)

Comment: Post the answer which ll help to someone else.

Comment: Hello, onCharacteristicChanged not able to call when i click on BLE device button, can you please help me out.please